# Hooking up a graph to a checkbox for adding additional Y value(s) from database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I've asked this a time or two, I admit, but I have kept running into spaghetti code and was hoping for a simple solution. I have a simple graph that I display a thing or two from my database on. I would like to hook it up to a checkbox so that every time the checkbox is clicked, the graph redraws and comes back with both options. 
Let's say I'm working with 2 files right now:
1) Financial Periods Controller (controller)
2) Index (view)
3) Financial Periods (model)

Here is my current graph code:

```
public ActionResult GetChartImage()         
{
    var sql = String.Format("select * from FinancialPeriods");
    var chartData = db.FinancialPeriods.SqlQuery(sql);

    var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400);

    myChart.AddSeries(name: "Prepaid Expenses", chartType: "Line", xValue: chartData, xField: "Year", yValues: chartData, yFields: "PrepaidExpenses");               
    myChart.AddSeries(name:  "Cash", chartType: "Line", xValue: chartData, xField: "Year", yValues: chartData, yFields: "Cash");               

    return File(myChart.ToWebImage().GetBytes(), "image/jpeg");
}
```

Let's say I have a checkbox "checkedPropertyValue" which goes to a database field calld "PropertyValue" and I want it charted with an xField of "Year" as well. Could anyone help me with the code to hook that up?